# Google Directory API insert user

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, google-admin-sdk

I'm really struggling with trying to add a new user with this API. I'm following every step at google Directory docs but I failed.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools



# Setup the Admin SDK Directory API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
   flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
   creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Admin SDK Directory API
#Insert User

body = { "name": 
           {"familyName": "Test", "givenName": "Mahalo"}, 
         "password": "mahalo@test", 
         "primaryEmail": "test@test.com", 

       }


user_add = service.users().insert(body=body).execute()
```

When I try the **insert** method I got this error

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned "Domain not found.">

If I try to run the **list** method like in the quickstart guide it runs perfect

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python

Comment: well the primary email cannot be @test.com. it needs to be your domain. Did you try with that?

Comment: That's it. I didn't notice that the primaryEmail require my domain.Thanks @plumSemPy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change my primaryEmail to `"primaryEmail": "test@mydomain.com"`